# How to order app.Config elements using VB NET AppSettings class?

Tags: vb.net, app-config

Below is a section of code which ADDs the <kbd><appSettings></kbd> element node in an app.config file. However this adds the <kbd><appSettings></kbd> block to PRECEDE the default <kbd><startup></kbd> element node.  Is there a way to add the <kbd><appSettings></kbd> block using the implementation below,such that this node FOLLOWS the <kbd><startup></kbd> node. I'm believe this can only be accomplished using **XmlDocument** library.

```
        Dim config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
        Dim appSettingSect As AppSettingsSection = config.GetSection("appSettings")
        If Not IsNothing(appSettingSect) AndAlso appSettingSect.Settings.Count = 0 Then
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("username", "user1234")
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("password", "12345678")
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)`
            config.Save()
        End If
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
```

Comment: Why is this a concern?

Comment: `config.GetSection()` returns a `ConfigurationSection`. After that, you just need `if appSettingSect.ElementInformation.IsPresent then ... end if`. You don't need to save twice.

Comment: I mean, when you can actually save these settings, is it important where the section is positioned?

Comment: Actually I did read while this was "hot" that order only matters in the ConfigurationSettings node. I was interested if I could have control over the order of elements. Thank you